# jQuery.off not working with a variable function name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a modular pattern for writing my Javascript code, and it is totally fun! But I'm stuck very badly at one situation.

My Namespace is as follows:

```
var settings, handlers, objects,
Namespace = {
    handlers: {
        //All event handlers go here
    },

    objects: {
        //All jquery button references go here
    },

    init: function(){
        //Initial stuff
    }
};

//Call init with the Namespace
```

I have a button which toggles between two different handlers for a `mousedown` event on a single object (a div), and handlers are properties of the `handlers` object. On `init`, one handler is automatically `on` to the div and works fine. Now when I click the toggle button, I'm trying to turn off the first handler so I can turn on the other, but it isn't working!

I turn `on` my first `mousedown` event handler (or all handlers for that matter!) like this:

```
Namespace.objects.someObject.on('mousedown', Namespace.handlers.mouseDownHandlerOne);
```

This works fine. When I try to turn it `off` like this:

```
Namespace.objects.someObject.off('mousedown', Namespace.handlers.mouseDownHandlerOne);
```

It doesn't work! No errors or warnings. If I just use `off` with `mousedown` without passing the handlers name, it works. But I need to separate between 2 different handlers!

How should it be done in a modular js environment?

Comment: Did you change the referenced function in `Namespace.handlers.mouseDownHandlerOne` somewhere in your code? Because if you did, it won't work.

Comment: Nope, I haven't changed the function. In fact my code was written and well tested in a non modular format, I'm just re-factoring it to be modular this way.

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the problem. We cannot do much given only the code posted here...

Comment: @FelixKling I wish I could! But I can't, employer policies mate! To summarize my problem, I can't turn off an event handler using its name which is stored in an object.

Comment: The only reasons why this wouldn't work is if either the object or the function changed for some reason.

Comment: Surprisingly when I toggle the other `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` handlers for the same object using the same method, it works like a charm! The only thing that doesn't work is when I turn off a particular `mousedown` handler for the object. I think there's a logical mistake somewhere in my code. I'll scan my code thoroughly and see if I can fix it. Or else form a simple fiddle!

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem, and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery .off method can take up to 3 arguments, use the following code:

```
Namespace.objects.someObject.off('mousedown', '**', Namespace.handlers.mouseDownHandlerOne);
```

Comment: It *can* take three arguments... it does not have to.